# How to apply a log function between two consecutives lines in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, finance

In a dataframe that contains prices on Brent per day, I am trying to apply a log function between two consecutive days. I guess the answer is simple but I couldn't find it.

```
ln[X(i+1)/X(i)] for each line
```

[image: img]

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
np.log(X.shift(-1) / X)
```

which `shift`s the data 1 step back (hence the minus) to get `X(i+1)` and then divides it by `X(i)`. Lastly, take the `log`.

Notes:

- The last row will be `NaN` because there is no `i+1`th data for them
- `np.log` is the natural logarithm not `log10`

Comment: I believe pandas catches divide-by-zero with `np.inf` (or maybe depends on pd version)

Comment: @tdy thank you very much, didn't know that!